# Horizontal Scroll view floating on UIView instead of Paging

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to do a horizontal scroll view similar to a paging type in which I am adding 3 views. I have put the scroll view in my storyboard above a UIView(myView) & have put constraints. Following are my constraints and my code for the same -

**ScrollView constraints**

[image]

**My code for the same -**

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.frame.width, myView.frame.height)
    
    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    
    let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.width, 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height))
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    
    
    let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.width*2, 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height))
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view3)
    
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.width*3, scrollView.frame.height)
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

**My Problems -**

**1) The scroll view floats when I run it in a smaller screen.**

2)My view1,view2,view3 width is not the same as of that of **myView**. Since myView is pinged to the view with (0,0,0,0), views "view1,view2,view3" should have the width & height of myView which should have a height equal to (mainView - TopView) & width that of the mainView.

Please help as I am in a damn need of this solution and I am not being able to figure out what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use constraints for MyView so you should probably use constraints for other views. The simplest way to make constraints in runtime using Cartography
https://github.com/robb/Cartography
Don't forget to set height constraint for scrollview in storyboard.

After in your viewDidLoad need to write something like this:

```
    let views = [UIView(), UIView(), UIView()]
    views.forEach {
        self.scrollView.addSubview($0)
        constrain($0) { view1 in
            view1.left == view1.superview!.left
            view1.right == view1.superview!.right
            view1.height == view1.superview!.height
        }
    }

    constrain(views[0], views[1], views[2]) { view1, view2, view3 in
        view1.top == view1.superview!.top
        view2.top == view1.bottom
        view3.top == view2.bottom
        view3.bottom == view3.superview!.bottom
    }
```